# Multiple filters and an aggregate in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I use a filter in connection with an aggregate in elasticsearch?

The official documentation gives only trivial examples for [filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html) and for [aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html) and no formal description of the query dsl - compare it e.g. with [postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html).

Through trying out I found following query, which is accepted by elasticsearch (no parsing errors), but ignores the given filters:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "term": {
          "_type": "logs"
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "dc": "eu-west-12"
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "status": "204"
        }
      },
      {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "from": 1398169707,
            "to": 1400761707
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "time_histo": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "1h"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "upstream_response_time",
            "percents": [
              98.0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some people suggest using `query` instead of `filter`. But the official documentation generally recommends [the opposite](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filters.html) for filtering on exact values. Another issue with `query`: while filters offer an [`and`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html), `query` does not.

Can somebody point me to documentation, a blog or a book, which describe writing non-trivial queries: at least an aggregate plus multiple filters.

Answer (score 37):

I ended up using a [filter aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) - not filtered query. So now I have 3 nested aggs elements.

I also use `bool` filter instead of `and` as recommended by @alex-brasetvik because of http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/

My final implementation:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "_type": "logs"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "dc": "eu-west-12"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "status": "204"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "from": 1398176502000,
                  "to": 1400768502000
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "time_histo": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "interval": "1h"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "name": {
              "percentiles": {
                "field": "upstream_response_time",
                "percents": [
                  98.0
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: you're possibly my favourite person right now. Have been battling with this for hours.

Comment: In this solution top aggr field is named "filtered", and that should not be mixed with http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html, so please use some other name (e.g. "aggresults") - under that name you will get results in response. Please check reference: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html and answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24823895/565525.

Answer (score 8):

Put your filter in a [`filtered`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)-query.

The top-level `filter` is for filtering search hits only, and not facets/aggregations. It was renamed to `post_filter` in 1.0 due to this quite common confusion.

Also, you might want to look into this post on why you often want to use `bool` and not `and`/`or`: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/

Answer (score 4):

more on @geekQ 's answer: to support filter string with space char,for multipal term search,use below:

```
{   "aggs": {
    "aggresults": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "term_1": "some text with space 1"
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "term_2": "some text with also space 2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs" : {
            "all_term_3s" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field":"term_3.keyword",
                    "size" : 10000,
                    "order" : {
                        "_term" : "asc" 
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }   },   "size": 0 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, as for the version *7.2*, I tried with something as follows to achieve multiple filters for aggregation:

- [`filter aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to filter for aggregation
- use [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to set up the compound query

```
POST movies/_search?size=0
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "term": {
              "genre": "action"
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "year": {
                "gte": 1800,
                "lte": 3000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "year_hist": {
          "histogram": {
            "field": "year",
            "interval": 50
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to enter 2 terms in filter? so inside must.term I want to add "term":{"genre":"action", "country":"USA"} something like this.

Comment: @makewhite it seems [`should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with proper `minimum_should_match` configured could help.