# Using aggregation with filters in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I have an elastic search running with documents like this one:

```
{
  id: 1,
  price: 620000,
  propertyType: "HO",
  location: {
    lat: 51.41999,
    lon: -0.14426
  },
  active: true,
  rentOrSale: "S",
}
```

I'm trying to use aggregates to get statistics about a certain area using aggregations and the query I'm using is the following:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "rentOrSale": "s"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "active": true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "geo_distance": {
              "distance": "15.0mi",
              "location": {
                "lat": 51.50735,
                "lon": -0.12776
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "propertytype_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "propertyType"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_price": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "bed_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "numberOfBedrooms"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_price": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in the result I can't see the aggregations. As soon as I remove either the bool or filtered part of the query I can see the aggregations. I can't figure out why this is happening, nor how do I get the aggregations for these filters. I've tried using the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807314/multiple-filters-and-an-aggregate-in-elasticsearch) but I've not been able to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query need to be slightly re-arranged - move the "filtered" further up and repeat the "query" command:

```
"query": {
  "filtered": {
   "query" : {
     "bool": {
          ...
     }
   },  
   "filter": {
    ...     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure I need to nest the aggregations? They aggregate separate thing and it seams to be working fine.

Comment: You're right - it does work, I've updated my answer.