# How to do AND / OR in Filter Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

In https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html we learn:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "t_shirts" : {
            "filter" : { "term": { "type": "t-shirt" } }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code show how we can aggs for t-shirt, but how do we do:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "t_shirts_or_shorts" : {
            "filter" : { "term": { "type": "t-shirt" } OR "term": { "type": "shorts" } }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "black_t_shirts" : {
            "filter" : { "term": { "type": "t-shirt" } AND "term": { "color": "black" } }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "must" and should clause in filter aggregation same as in query.

**Query1:**

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "t_shirts": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "type.keyword": "t-shirt"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type.keyword": "shorts"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query2:**

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "t_shirts": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "type.keyword": "t-shirt"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "color.keyword": "black"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't query 1 and query 2 the same, why does the first return OR and the second return AND?

Comment: @AeroWang Sorry, have corrected. It should have been "must" instead of "should"

Answer (score 0):

You can combine filter criteria using the bool tag, much like you can query clauses.
You can also check this: [Multiple filters and an aggregate in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807314/multiple-filters-and-an-aggregate-in-elasticsearch)